# Axios PUT request -React

Tags: javascript, react-native, api, axios, put

I want to send a put request to modify the command part of my JSON file. Here is my JSON;

```
{
  "users": [
    {
      "hostname": "xxx.xxx.xxx.xx",
      "password": "password1",
      "command": "command1",
      "id": 1
    },
    {
      "hostname": "xxx.xxx.xxx.xx",
      "password": "password2",
      "command": "command2",
      "id": 2
    },
    {
      "hostname": "xxx.xx.xx.xxx",
      "password": "password3",
      "command": "command3",
      "id": 3
    }
  ]
}
```

In App.js I send put request like this;

```
stopPC(id){        
            axios.put('http://localhost:3002/users/'+id,{
              command: 'stop'
            })   
  }
```

And I have tried this;

```
axios({
            method: 'put',
            url: 'http://localhost:3002/users/'+ id,
            data: {
              hostname: id.hostname,
              password: id.password,
              command:  'stop'
            }    
  });
```

In both, I got the following output in the JSON file.

```
{
  "users": [
    {
      "command": "stop",
      "id": 1
    },
    {
      "hostname": "xxx.xxx.xxx.xx",
      "password": "password2",
      "command": "command2",
      "id": 2
    },
    {
      "hostname": "xxx.xxx.xxx.xx",
      "password": "password3",
      "command": "command3",
      "id": 3
    }
  ]
}
```

I want to change only the command information while keeping the hostname and password information the same.
I'm not sure where I went wrong, I'd be glad if you could help.

Comment: I guess the [PATCH](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Methods/PATCH) (partial modification) method would be more appropriate in this case. From the context you give, the error seems to come from the backend.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If `id` is of type `Number` (which I think it is), `id.hostname` and `id.password` would be `undefined`, so basically

```json
{
  hostname: id.hostname,
  password: id.password,
  command: 'stop'
}
```

and

```json
{
  command: 'stop'
}
```

are the same to Javascript and you're effectively sending the same payload. I think that the best way of solving this would be changing how the backend handles the incoming payload by just changing the properties that came in the request. If you don't have access to changing the backend, you would have to get or read the current stored value and use that in the payload. Something like

```js
user = axios.get('http://localhost:3002/users/'+id).then(r => r.data)
axios.put('http://localhost:3002/users/'+id,{
            hostname: user.hostname,
            password: user.password,
            command: 'stop'
         })
```

Also, `PUT` is meant to be used used to replace a record, and `PATCH` to update the existing one, which sounds more like what you want to do. Maybe just try `axios.patch` and it may work.

Answer (score 0):

I did quite the same than @rodrigo-naranjo except I embedded the put call in the response of the get call:

```
  axios.get("http://localhost:3002/users/" + id).then((r) => {
    let user = r.data;
    axios.put("http://localhost:3002/users/" + id, {
      hostname: user.hostname,
      password: user.password,
      command: "stop",
    });
  });
```

*with `id` an input value from your app context.*